# static IP not working on Huawei HG8240T

Tags: networking, router, static-ip

I'm having trouble setting up static IP for certain devices in my network.

I connect to the internet the following way:

> Computer -- (cable/wifi) -- [TD-W8980] -- cable -- [HG8240T] -- fibre -- internet

The actual internet connection is done via the Huawei HG8240T which is a 4 port fibre to the home router.
As the HG8240T has no wireless the only connection to it is my TP-Link TD-W8980.

The Huawei router is running the DHCP server and the TP-Link has the DHCP serve disabled.

I have entered a number of MAC addresses that I want to have a static IP on under the respective options of the Huawei

> LAN > DHCP Static IP Configuration

However even with 1 minute DHCP lease the devices do not assume the static IP assigned in the router config.

If I try to reduce the dynamic IP range in the DHCP settings of the Huawei to anything else than 254 I get the message:

> The primary address pool does not allow configuration of a new routing
>   policy. You are advised to enlarge the primary address pool scale.

Unfortunately I did not find any ridge mode in the settings.

Comment: Why don't you configure your network settings manually on the desired devices?

Comment: Haven't thought about it. Would you reduce the DHCP range and assign an IP outside the range? I tried that before and the Huawei behaves oddly (cant remember the message).

Comment: What port on the TD-W8980 is connected to the HG8240T?

Comment: @seb: yes. Supposing you are in a /24 subnet, you could assign a 100 (or whatever suits your need) ip pool to your dhcp server, and use the rest for manual configuration. What does 'behaves oddly' really mean?

Comment: @Alex the message is "The primary address pool does not allow configuration of a new routing policy. You are advised to enlarge the primary address pool scale." and it won't accept anything else than 254.

Comment: How did you tried to set up your DHCP pool?

Answer (score 6):

#### The range must *include* static addresses.

Static IP addresses were ignored if I configured them with the classic assumption that static IP addresses are configured *outside* of dynamic address range:

```
Range start: 192.168.1.101
Range end:   192.168.1.199


Static IP 1: 192.168.1.11
Static IP 2: 192.168.1.12
etc...
```

After some trying I found out that the Range needs to *include* statically assigned addresses. So in this case, adjustment

```
Range start: 192.168.1.2
```

caused static IP configuration to work normally and static entries were no longer ignored.

Obviously, in Huawei routers, the "Range" is understood a bit differently.